# Eclipse: Code in Java file appears to have disappeared mysteriously. Why should this happen?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I was working on a Java file in Eclipse. I saved the file (but didn't close the Eclipse interface) and then closed my laptop. When I open it next **ALL** of the code in that file has been replaced by unreadable characters (boxes). I close the file and make a few attempts to open it again and then there's **NO** text in it, there were several hundred lines of code when I last saved the file. All the other files in the project have code in them.
Why has this happened? Is it because the computer went to sleep without closing the interface? I've done it before bu this hasn't happened. 
More importantly, how do I fix this? **The replace/restore from local history options mentioned in some answers did not work, with a 'No local history available for this resource' message.**

Comment: Sounds like you just learnt a valuable lesson on the importance of some form of version control ;). From what you describe it seems as if the file's contents were corrupted, and sadly if there's no local history available the chances of recovering what was originally in there are next to none.

Comment: Try running a ScanDisk (assuming you're running Windows) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: When has ScanDisk every solved any problem? :p

Comment: @Tobb It has actually worked for me in the past. I'll admit that it's a bit of a Hail Mary here, but it's worth a shot.